# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table Laravel 8

Tags: php, foreign-keys, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

```php
Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('category_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('menu_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')
        ->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
        ->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I run `php artisan:migrate`, I get the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `mieaceh`.`category_menu` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `category_menu` add constraint `category_menu_menu_id_foreign` foreign key (`menu_id`) references `menus` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: Just change `$table->increments('id');` to `$table->id();`

Answer (score 4):

This is due to mismatch of datatype of foreign key column and the referenced column most likely

When you create a primary key with `$table->id()` the datatype of the auto incrementing id column is `unsignedBigInteger` so you must have foreign key also with the same datatype

```php
Schema::create('category_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('menu_id');
        $table->foreign('menu_id')->references('id')
            ->on('menus')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')
            ->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
});
```

You shouldn't make the columns in a pivot table nullable for the foreign keys to maintain data integrity.

Also be consistent with the datatype for primary key columns as well as definitions - when using `$table->id()` keep that consistent across all migrations for all tables. That way you will have less chances of mismatch when defining foreign keys as `$table->unsignedBigInteger()`

Comment: I still got the same error, errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Answer (score 0):

laravel migrations files contains a datetime slug that determine which file will be migrated first

***notice the order***

```
2021_10_11_101533_create_posts_table.php
2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
```

when you run

```
php artisan migrate
```

posts table will be migrated first and it contains a foriegn key

> user_id

which references a primary key on users table

> id

but the users table doesn't exists yet, to fix this issues change the files names and make sure users table migrate first like this

***notice the order***

```
2014_10_10_000000_create_users_table.php
2021_10_11_101533_create_posts_table.php
```

***short pattern for declaring a foreign key***

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
```